# Select country through Jquery in Origin Address of Shipping Settings

Tags: shipping, jquery, prototype-js, system-configuration, magento2.3.5-p1

I am trying to set Country for Origin address using jQuery in Shipping Settings of Sales (Store Configuration).

The issue is, on change of country option using jquery, the ajax to fetch region is not getting called.
I found that the region is bind using prototype.js.

```
<script>
 require([
    'jquery',
    'uiRegistry'
 ], function ($, uiRegistry) {
    $(function () {
        let bodySelector = $('body');
        let sectionName = 'shipping_origin_';
        let countryIdSelector = bodySelector.find('#' + sectionName + 'country_id');
        let postCodeSelector = bodySelector.find('#' + sectionName + 'postcode');
        postCodeSelector.on('change', function (e) {
            countryIdSelector.val('IN').change();
        });
    });
 });
</script>
```

Please help.
Thank you.